# Swift: Writing code that will call random item from array and not call that item again

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm writing a basic truth or dare app as a practice project and I'm running into an issue when I try to make an array for truths/dares. I want to randomly call a dare but not have that dare be available as an option when I call the method again. I tried using array.remove(at: ) but I then run into issues with immutable classes/methods.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
var wildDares = [
    "Wild Dare A",
    "Wild Dare B",
    "Wild Dare C",
    "Wild Dare D",
    "Wild Dare E"]

func randomWildDare() -> String {
    let randomNum = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextInt(upperBound: wildDares.count)

    if wildDares.count == 1 {
        return "You're out of dares. Select a new pack or click 'New Game' in the menu section." } else {
            //wildDares.remove(at: randomNum)
            return wildDares[randomNum]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply mark your method as `mutating` if you're using a struct.  e.g. `mutating func randomWildDate() -> String`

Comment: "but I then run into issues with immutable classes/methods." What issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using GameplayKit to shuffle your dares, but shuffle is built in to swift itself now.

```
struct DareStore {
    private var dares: [String]
    init(dares: [String]) {
        self.dares = dares.shuffled()
    }

    mutating func next() -> String? {
        if dares.count > 0 {
            return dares.removeFirst()
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

In this DareStore you see we provide the init with an array of dares, and we there handle shuffling of it. Now whenever next() is called, it will just remove and return the first of the shuffled dares, until no more are left.

```
var dares = DareStore(dares: ["1", "2", "3"])
while let dare = dares.next() {
    print(dare)
}
```

Comment: the while statement (second to last line) gives me the following error: "Statements are not allowed at the top level". Any idea why I'm getting this? I would assume it's because I wrote your second snippet of code outside the struct. Am I supposed to make a new struct or have the second snippet of code within the DareStore struct?

Comment: The second code example, is purely a way to show how to use the DareStore. Your error "Statements are not allowed at the top level", means that you have placed this code somewhere it was not supposed to be. 

You will properly have a viewcontroller that holds the DateStore, and then let a button click (or something) call the next() method.